# Special characters in Django HTML templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to write somethings with special characters in Django HTML templates like "é" or "ê", but it's is not working. And Django returns this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 248: invalid start byte
```

This is the entire traceback:
    Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'survey',
 'south',
 'django_reset',
 'chartkick',
 'registration')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/filipeferminiano/Documents/django/panorama/survey/views.py" in home
  35.         return render(request, 'home.html')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  162.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  127.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  43.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  46.         source, display_name = self.load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py" in load_template_source
  38.                     return (fp.read().decode(settings.FILE_CHARSET), filepath)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py" in decode
  16.     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /
Exception Value: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 230: invalid start byte
```

The view that renders the template:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        browser_stats = [['Chrome', 52.9], ['Firefox', 27.7], ['Opera', 1.6],
                     ['Internet Explorer', 12.6], ['Safari', 4]]
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

The url of the template:

```
url(r'^$', 'survey.views.home', name='home'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

- Please put

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

at the start of your .py file.

- That .py file has to be a UTF-8 without BOM file (Encoding - Convert to UTF-8 without BOM from Notepad++)
- Also, your text strings that contain unicode characters should start with a `u`. So you should write something like `text=u'unicode here'`.

If you still see the same erorr please provide the full stacktrace. Also, `<meta charset="utf-8">` is client related and doesn't have anything to do with django exceptions.

Comment: But in the views.py there is just a redirect for the html file. And the text is not a variable rendered from django to html, it's a pure HTML text.

Comment: Please update your question with the full stacktrace of the exception. Also, is your html template in UTF-8 without bom ? Convert it with notepad++ if not. Finally, provide the parts of views.py and urls.py that render the mentioned template.

Comment: Ok, i already updated. And the files are encoded with utf-8 without bom

Comment: This seems like a problem in your template. For reasons unknown to me, your template contains non-unicode characters so django cannot decode it. Have you double checked that your template is actually converted to UTF-8 w/o BOM ? Also, as you can understand there are some offending characters: Try to start with a clean template for home.html that *works* and put more text gradually until you find out which are the offending characters... I can't think of any better solution :(

Comment: Ok, I already solved the problem. I deleted all the old files and replaced with new ones with same name and code. Thanks for the help!